# Large data line chart in aws quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to visualize data in AWS quicksight by using a simple line chart.
The chart display only the top 200 points and not the full data range which is connected to the analysis

Is there anyway to display a full line chart of the data?

Is there anyway to display the bottom 200 points not only the top ones?

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select the Settings on your chart, and go to the 'X-axis':

   [image: Settings on your chart]
2. Select the X-axis from Format Visual:

   [image: Format Visual]
3. Change the Number of data points to maximum feasible:

   [image: Number of Data Points]

If it is not letting you put more than 200, then go to 'Group/Color' and specify the number of groups you want to show; the higher the number of groups, the lower the max-value feasible in point #3.

Comment: Is it possible to "scroll" through the data points? I am fine by seeing only 200 at a time, but now I can only see the 200 _latest_, Can I scroll back, and see 200 in the middle, without changing any of these limits?